# Triangle shape view in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view, photo

I am doing a photo collage app. I now need a way to draw triangle custom views in layout. is this possible in android layout. if so please suggest me some ideas

my layout is as follows

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/viewLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.wglxy.example.pinchzoompan.PanZoomView
android:id="@+id/zoomview1"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<com.wglxy.example.pinchzoompan.PanZoomView1
android:id="@+id/zoomview2"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<com.wglxy.example.pinchzoompan.PanZoomView2
android:id="@+id/zoomview3"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

three custom views in my layout. i want it to be in different shapes.  a sample image is as follows

[image: photo collage]

Like this layouts in the images. 
thanks in advance

Comment: u need images what problems u r facing

Comment: if you see my layout. the layout is similar to the 3rd frame in the sample image i gave. i want to develop a layout like the one in the 2nd frame from the sample image.

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem with you!

Comment: I want a solution too.

Comment: vote my question so that this question can get some attention and people can help.